# Set start and end time of a calendar entry based on another column

Tags: sharepoint-calendar

I have a Calendar that has a column which is a selection of school blocks like A, B, C, and D.

Rather than having to enter required start and end times I want teachers to be able to choose one of the blocks, and then have the start and end times auto-completed based on the Block selected.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

- You can add a Workflow using SharePoint Designer, which OnChange sets the values.
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj554671.aspx
- You can add (Client-Side) code to the New/Edit form, which before save calculates the values
  https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a
- Server-Side code is an option but no longer the best option in SharePoint Online.

With these options you can use the values as if they were entered.

If you only want to display the values in Views you could also use a *Calculated Column* to (dynamically) calculated the dates based on the block selection

Comment: Ok, so I have a List Workflow associated with the Calendar, how do I find OnChange?